# Disable user account for FRP, allow only work managed accounts

Tags: android, android-security, android-for-work

**Prelude**:

The client wants to install EMM for his owner devices. Sometimes the user wants to use the device as work device (only taxi and couriers apps) and sometimes the user wants to use the device as his own (install games, social apps, and his own Google accounts).

**Situation**:

The client wants to store his gsuite accounts in *FRP storage* (to have the ability to unlock a phone in case employee leave organization) but doesn't want an employee to unlock the phone after FR entering his personal account credentials.

**Example:**

I added two work account programmatically (like described [here](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/security#enable_enterprise_factory_reset_protection)). But after the user gets the phone he entered his personal Gmail account to use Gmail, other apps. How can I programmatically or maybe from DPC app prevents user recover access to the phone using his personal account after Factory Reset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, finally. The link to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/security#disable_factory_reset_protection).
I need just to create a bundle with google plus ids of accounts that will have the opportunity to recover device after factory reset.

And after that need to send a broadcast to notify the system that these values were changed.

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    // list of recovery accounts
    val recoveryAccounts = arrayOf(
        "115273111154663031432", 
        "110369192556268846321", 
    )
    bundle.putStringArray("factoryResetProtectionAdmin", recoveryAccounts)
    
    mAdminComponentName = DeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(context)
    // set restrictions
    mDevicePolicyManager.setApplicationRestrictions(mAdminComponentName, "com.google.android.gms", bundle)
    
    // send broadcast
    val broadcastIntent = Intent("com.google.android.gms.auth.FRP_CONFIG_CHANGED")
    broadcastIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gms")
    broadcastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND)
    applicationContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
```

Comment: How do you get the id of recovery accounts?

Comment: I tried this code but this issue comes.

Exception come on this line: - mDevicePolicyManager.setApplicationRestrictions(mAdminComponentName, "com.google.android.gms", bundle)

java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized

Answer (score 0):

Off topic.
To get the id of recovery accounts try this: [https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix=true&apix_params={"resourceName":"people/me","personFields":"metadata"}](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22:%22people/me%22,%22personFields%22:%22metadata%22%7D)
Push "Execute" and login with needed account. It'll be shown in "id" field of response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried above code but this issue comes. Exception come on this line: - mDevicePolicyManager.setApplicationRestrictions(mAdminComponentName, "com.google.android.gms", bundle) java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized